# header row template in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have created an ng-grid and want to customise **Header Row Template** of the grid as i need to add total items in header instead of the footer, but want the same view as footer (i mean the whole row ). I already know about headerCellTemplate and also have already tried it but its not what i am looking for ! if you can help i will be so thankful to you :)
here is sample of my code

```
$scope.myData = [{"name": "Moroni", "age": 50},
{"name": "Tiancum", "age": 53},
{"name": "Jacob", "age": 27},
{"name": "Nephi", "age": 54},
{"name": "Alex", "age": 53},
{"name": "Jhonny", "age": 22},
{"name": "Ben", "age": 11},
],
        $scope.gridOptions = { 
            data: 'myData', 
            columnDefs: [
                            { field: 'name', displayName: 'Candiate name' },
                            { field: 'age', displayName: 'Age', headerCellTemplate: myHeaderCellTemplate }
                        ]
        };
```

Comment: Do you mean you can't figure out the right css styling to make the header look like the footer? Or? Maybe a picture of what you are hoping to achieve would help.

Comment: hi @lmyers thanks for responding what i actually want is to add a new row above the header (a full row ) containing some heading text in it, so is it possible to edit headerTemplate just as footerTemplate?

Comment: You don't need to do that as part of the grid. Just add a div above the grid and put whatever you want in it. You can use the same styles as the footer does to make it match.

Comment: i also did the same way you suggested @lmyers thanks allot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that as part of the grid. Just add a div above the grid and put whatever you want in it. You can use the same styles as the footer does to make it match.